# Do I need to checkin sbt-launcher.jar into an sbt managed project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've seen several scala projects on github which bundles these files into the root of their sbt-managed project:

- sbt.cmd
- sbt (shell script)
- sbt-launcher.jar

Is this the recommended practice ?

**UPDATE** One github project that does this is [Scalala](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a bug when `sbt-launcher.jar` was in the root directory on "scratch mode". I'm sure it's fixed but since then I keep the jar in a separate directory if I feel like putting it under the root of the project.

If sbt launcher is bundled on github, I would also include the license.

I would guess including these files is not the most common practice but I think it's good when you want to clone and not sure the machine you're cloning to has `sbt` set up.

Answer (score 0):

We had to do exactly that in projects that live behind very restrictive corporate firewalls. We even commit the lib_managed dir because access to repo's is restricted so updates have to be done by someone with appropriate permission.

It's also convenient to have a known version of your build tools some times.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think these files should be included if it is a github project meant for anybody. Try to keep it as simple as possible.